# Syntax error (comma) in query expression of SQL Statement in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

Syntax error (comma) in query expression '(Date() BETWEEN Бронь.Дата_заселения=[Введите дату заселения] AND Бронь.Дата_выселения=[Введите дату выселения]), Номера.Класс=[Введите класс номера], Номера.Корпус=[Введите корпус], Номера.Этаж=[Введите этаж], Номера.Местность=[Введите местность номера]'.

I have no idea what comma is meant.

This is the query:

```
SELECT Номера.Код_номера, Бронь.Дата_заселения, Бронь.Дата_выселения, Номера.Класс, Номера.Корпус, Номера.Этаж, Номера.Местность, COUNT(*) AS Количество_свободных_номеров
FROM Номера INNER JOIN Бронь ON Номера.Код_номера=Бронь.Номер
GROUP BY Номера.Код_номера, Бронь.Дата_заселения, Бронь.Дата_выселения, Номера.Класс, Номера.Корпус, Номера.Этаж, Номера.Местность
HAVING (Date() BETWEEN Бронь.Дата_заселения=[Введите дату заселения] AND Бронь.Дата_выселения=[Введите дату выселения]), Номера.Класс=[Введите класс номера], Номера.Корпус=[Введите корпус], Номера.Этаж=[Введите этаж], Номера.Местность=[Введите местность номера];
```

Comment: You have commas in the `HAVING` clause.  These are not appropriate.

Comment: ...you should be separating those terms with e.g. `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Also the logic of your `HAVING` clause is not entirely clear to me.  Only columns appearing in the `GROUP BY` list or aggregates can appear in `HAVING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use commas in a `having` clause. If you need to query groups that adhere to all the conditions, you should use the `and` relational operator between them, not commas.